# Google Map список мест поблизости

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Возможно ли с помощью Google Map API получить список мест(кафе, рестораны, парки и т.д) поблизости после того как пользователь ввёл свой город и регион? если нет то есть ли другие варианты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, можно. Вот список [типов мест](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=ru), а вот так в документации прописан [пример запроса](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id?hl=ru).

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=52.524580,13.395186&type=restaurant&rankby=distance&key=API_KEY
```

Всё что вам нужно это сделать запрос на получение координат широты и долготы по названию города.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!